# We have installed webpshere 9 in our production environment. My question is related to Webcontainer thread pool

Tags: websphere

Can webcontainer thread pool size exceed beyond maximum size set even if we dont have allow Thread allocation beyond maximum thread size unchecked. Since we have observed maximum webcontainer thread count exceed to 162 with maximum size set at 150 and minimum to 50.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you observe the thread count in this case? While in your configuration, the pool should never have more than 150 threads at one time, the thread index (part of the thread name, as in "WebContainer : 162") could be higher than 150. The WebSphere thread pool increments the thread index every time it creates a new thread in a pool, regardless of whether every lower number is currently in use. Since a pool with a minimum size smaller than the maximum size can delete unused threads, it's not at all uncommon to go through delete/create cycles that leaves you with an index higher than the maximum size.

If you are still concerned that the thread pool is misbehaving, you could double-check the pool size by forcing a javacore (running `kill -3` against the process ID, or requesting a javacore in the administrative console or through the server's JVM MBean) and counting the threads with "WebContainer" in the name. It should be very unlikely that there are more than 150 of them, and if there are, I'd probably recommend reporting that to IBM as a possible product bug.

Answer (score 0):

As Jarid mentioned one way to check is doing thread dump, but the other, maybe a little less invasive is to use Tivoli Perf Viewer from the web console and monitor the WebContainer thead pool stats. Then you will easily see min/max/avg stats of how the pool is utilized.